# ActionAttribute DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can't figure out how to accomplish the following:
I have an attribute:

```
public class Authorize : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
      private readonly IAccessPermissionRepository _repository;

      public Authorize(IAccessPermissionRepository repository)
      {
          _repository = repository;
      }
      ...
   }
```

The IAccessPermissionRepository is resolved by default IoC
and I use it in controller class like this

```
 [ServiceFilter(typeof(Authorize))]
        public IActionResult Index()
```

but now I want to pass additional parameters to constructor, different for every action and controller. Normally I would just use constructor for that but.. you see.

Comment: It's an older discussion and I'm not familiar enough with Core to offer much insight, but https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1582 seems to ask the same as you and has a workaround in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use TypeFilter instead of ServiceFilter, like so:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(HasDummyPrivilegeAttribute), Arguments = new object[] { "dummyId" })]
```

And HasDummyPrivilegeAttribute looks like:

```
    public class HasDummyPrivilegeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _idParameterName;
    private readonly IAccessPermissionRepository _repo;

    public HasServicePrivilegeAttribute(
        string idParameterName,
        [FromServices] IAccessPermissionRepository repo)
    {
        _idParameterName = idParameterName;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //TODO Something awesome here with _idParameterName and _repo 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that one.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much. It's badly documented and the syntax is bad.